# easy_install conda is failing with Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('menuinst') error

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda

easy_install conda is failing with

> error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('menuinst')

[image]

I am on python 3.6.5 version. Can someone point me in the direction of troubleshooting this issue.

Comment: Are there special reasons you are not downloading and running the installer? https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/

Comment: don't have admin rights

Comment: As the page @ReblochonMasque linked to says, *You do not need administrative or root permissions to install Anaconda if you select a user-writable install location.*

Comment: Please do not put code or terminal input/output into images. See here for why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably download and successfully run the installer, even without administrative privileges.

> You do not need administrative or root permissions to install Anaconda
>   if you select a user-writable install location.

https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/